# iPad app inbox "stuck"

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, global-inbox, ipad

In the iPad app the inbox shows unread notifications as a badge. When you tap on the icon a list pops up with the unread notices subtly highlighted in light blue. After you tap on one of the notices the icon badge and blue highlight disappear... Until today.  Now the highlight does not reset, and the inbox icon badge reappears with the same number a few minutes later.  It's worth noting that all the notifications I'm seeing are old ones from a few days ago that I had already read.

On the web interface the badge is absent but the 'unread' highlight is visible.

After visiting the inbox on the web, the iPad is back to "normal" for now. The badge and blue highlighting is gone.

Comment: Interesting-my unread notifications didn't show up as a badge, just the usual red number in the inbox, but the rest of your report happened to me today.  I made it happen a number of times (screenshots available if anyone wants them), I had to try a couple of times on Safari before it acknowledged that I had read it, and the iPad app's fine now! Would you mind letting me know if this message worked for you? Then I'll know if your message worked for me, and we can report the findings! I won't be checking back until the morning.

Comment: I've had 3 new notifications since I reset things in the web interface and it's stuck again, same behavior.

Comment: [Seems like a similar issue in the Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256446/inbox-items-not-marked-read).

Comment: My iPad and Android are both stuck. The only difference is that the number doesn't keep reappearing in my Android inbox, though no matter how many times I read it, the new message won't go away! Maybe it's a mobile thing. I imagine you've seen this @Brian Nickel, but I'm pinging you just in case! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should be fixed in a build rolling out now (to correct the endpoint the Mobile application hits). We are making huge inbox changes behind the scenes and this slipped through, sorry!

Comment: Any chance we'll get details about those huge changes? What's their goal? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard remember when the inbox was "inbox" and "notifications"? On the back-end that was the old system, old tables, old queues, and worked entirely different. It's been running alongside the new the entire time. Some things like Mobile pushes, API, etc. that predate the inbox were still based on the old. It's finally causing a problem and made me tear it all out - re-writing it against the new data store/code. It's a worthwhile change, but it's *everywhere*. **So many** things are tied to the inbox - it's quite a project.

Comment: Oh my, had no idea. Reminds me a bit of Windows, I read somewhere it's still built on the same core as DOS and Microsoft just can't get rid of it.