# Inbox items not marked "read"

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

Since yesterday, new items (comment @replies) in the inbox aren't being marked "read", even after tapping and viewing.

Motorola Moto X (1st gen) - Android 4.4.4
Stack Exchange Android App
Version 1.0.62

Comment: Similar bug on MSO for the [ios-app](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294242/possible-bug-in-ios-app-showing-wrong-message-count)

Comment: I have also force-stopped the app and cleared the data.

Comment: I'm having a similar issue on the iOS app (v1.3.1 on iOS 8 on iPhone 5). The most recent comment in my inbox, which I read weeks ago, is showing is unread and reading it doesn't change the status. This is only happening on the app - in the browser, it's fine.

Comment: I was able to confirm this last night on my phone (Android 5.1; SE 1.0.62) though it appears to have magically fixed itself after I cleared out my notifications in the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should be fixed in a build rolling out now. We are making huge inbox changes behind the scenes and this slipped through, sorry!